# Make Tomcat 9 ignore Http Basic information

Tags: tomcat, iis, isapi

I have a setup with IIS + Tomcat (using Tomcat connector in between). the tomcat site is completely unprotected when accessed locally (http://localhost:8080), IIS however requiret basic auth. The setup works fine except that Tomcat seems to get confused when it sees the http basic Authorization header.

A simple example:

- access http://localhost:8080/mysite => ok
- access http://localhost:8080/mysite (with HTTP Authorization header: basic ....) => 401

What I would like to achieve is that IIS should handle the security, and Tomcat should ignore the Authorization header that will be passed on from IIS into Tomcat. Any ideas how I could achieve that?

Comment: Tomcat should ignore `HTTP Basic` request headers if the application isn't configured to require authentication. Post a protocol trace of what you are observing.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: Thanks for the response. The Tomcat app that I am trying to access is geowebcache 1.11. I think the auth mechanism (http basic) that this app uses is what interferes my request. I remember seeing something about spring security in geowebcache. I will check and report what I find.

Comment: Geowebcache comes predefined with a user called 'geowebcache', the funny thing is that as long as I match that username in my Http Basic Auth header, I am allowed to access unprotected url's inside geowebcache. The password doesnt have to be correct(?) However, using unknown username and geowebcache throws 401 (even though I am trying to access unprotected urls).

Comment: There is a filter inside web-config of geowebcache "org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy" that is responsible for the 401. Uncommenting this filter resolves my issue since the security is completely handled by IIS.

Comment: When trying to create my seup, I stumbled across two attributes on the tomcat AJP connector that is useful when attempting to share auth information between IIS and Tomcat: tomcatAuthentication and tomcatAuthorization https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so now I have a completely working solution where IIS handles all Authentication. The "root" site in IIS is unprotected, but everything sent to Tomcat through the connector requires authentication. All you need to do is protect the virtual jakarta-directory that is created during the Tomcat connector setup, eg:

```
  <location path="jakarta">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" /> <!-- deny anonymous access -->
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

If you want to perform authorization in Tomcat based on the principal set by IIS, look into the attributes tomcatAuthentication and tomcatAuthorization found on the Connector element in your Tomcats server.xml, eg: